# Visual Studio 2010 can't locate ODP.NET provider

Tags: .net, oracle

I'm trying to setup a .net project using oracle\s odp.net provider. I have installed Oracle Express server. Additionally I installed Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) so I can get the provider itself. 
Unfortunately Visual Studio seems unable to auto-detect it, i.e. when I click Add connection in the Servers view, there is no provider different from the default one for .NET and OLE DB. Is there any additional step I'm missing here ? I don't see any Oracle related registry entry related, could this be the problem ?

Thank you

Comment: Is this Visual Studio express?

Answer (score 0):

I have these relevant products installed:

- Oracle Data Provider for NET
- Oracle Providers for ASP.NET
- Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio
- Oracle Provider for OLE DB
- Oracle Objects for OLE
- Oracle Data Access Components Documentation for Visual Studio 2010

Check for them in your Oracle Universal Installer. If you're missing any, make sure you install them, and try again!

Comment: what versions of these do you have for VS2010?  Im struggling to find a working combination for VS2010 and oracle database version 11.2 (also known as 11g).  I tried installing 11.1 which didnt find visual studio and contained some 64 bit ASP.net scripts despite coming being the 32 bit version.  I have also tried 12.1 which says it doesnt work with 11 when you try and install it.  Any help would be appreciated otherwise Im probably just going to be randomly trying versions!